# Search algorithm to find integer input that produces the first 'True' (bool: 1) occurence of a computationally expensive boolean function

Tags: optimization, search-algorithms, integer-programming, binary-search

A boolean-valued function defined in the set of positive integers, $\mathcal Z$.

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 0, &n_{min}\le n < n\ast\\1, &n\ast\le n\le n_{max} \end{cases} ; n \in \mathcal Z $$

$f(n)$ is computationally expensive and it's analytical form (a closed-form equation producing these binary-valued outputs is unknown, since it is the result of a time-domain simulation of complicated system of non-linear PDEs meeting certain exit conditions etc.). Furthermore, $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{n}}$ is also obviously not available.

The goal is to compute $n\ast$, i.e. the first occurrence of the integer-valued function input, $n$ that produces a Boolean $1$. Needless to say, this can be trivially achieved in computer code by using a simple $for$ loop and rejecting the values of $n$ one by one, until we hit $n\ast$.

The lower and upper bounds, $n_{min}$ and $n_{max}$ are known apriori.

However, given the expensive nature of computing $f(n)$, I am looking for an efficient algorithm beyond this naive implementation, especially one that requires small number of function evaluations. A pseudo-code implementation of your proposed solution would be much welcome too.

A conceptual schematic/visualisation of the problem is also shown here, purely to aid the understanding of the task at hand [image]

Comment: Are $n_{min}$ and $n_{max}$ known? ​ ​

Comment: Yes. Maybe the sentence is buried deep in the question that it's not clearly visible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Algorithm ​ ​

Comment: Sure. But this typically (at-least in textbook style implementations) requires a sorted array, to begin with. My function values are not available apriori. They are super-expensive to compute. You may think them as "each iteration of the binary search taking an enormous amount of time", i.e. cost per iteration is very high. Given this information, I am looking to understand if binary search is still my best bet?

Comment: Monte Carlo approach could be useful in practice. I want to add, that if functions doesn't have any property which we can exploit then there is no free lunch, i.e. checking one by one is the best you can do. If you function is monitonically non-decreasing(if I see it correctly from your question), then golden search is the way to go. It should outperform binary search.

Comment: @RickyDemer I concur. Binary search is the right answer. It would require log (nmax - nmin) evaluations of f.

Comment: Binary search is the best you can do if you don't know anything about $n^*$. It has the best worst-case guarantee. There may be a better algorithm in practice (probably start with a heuristic and finish with binary search) if you have information about $n^*$. But whether such heuristics are worth exploring depends entirely on what you know about $n^*$. You may want to ask a follow-up question about that, where you give the details of what $f$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Algorithm).

You know that the correct value is somewhere in the range $[n_\min,n_\max]$, so pick $t = \lfloor (n_\min+n_\max)/2 \rfloor$ (the point halfway in the middle), and evaluate $f(t)$.  This will either tell you that $n^*$ is in $[n_\min,t]$ or that $n^*$ is in $[t+1,n_\max]$.  Now you can repeat on the smaller interval.  Each time, the width of the interval decreases by a factor of two, so after $\lg (n_\max-n_\min)$ iterations, you will find the correct value of $n^*$.  This is much faster than trying all $n_\max-n_\min$ possible values of $n^*$.